# Error casting varchar containing a number expressed in scientific notation to decimal

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am currently working on a ETL project where data from mongoDB is getting converted to relational database and stored in SQL Server. The problem I am having is that some of the numbers in the same field in mongoDB is stored as decimal (0.058823) and sometimes using scientific notation (5.8823e-02).

When I was working with Postgres the values in either format got passed as double values and I had no issues querying with either format. This does not seem to be the case with SQL Server.

Currently all the data is passed as `varchar` and in the view of the same table I am using the following code:

```
CAST (CASE 
         WHEN [fieldname] LIKE '%e%' 
            THEN log([fieldname]) 
            ELSE [fieldname] 
      END AS DECIMAL(30, 20)) AS [FieldName1]
```

There are also list in a field that I am turning into substring and casting which requires using CTE. This is turning my code from 100+ to almost 600+ lines. Was wondering if there is a simpler way?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: The number 5.8823e-02 is not a natural log number, it is in [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E-notation). It is in fact the exact same value as 0.058823, just written differently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server supports both scientific notation and "regular" decimals.

Here's a simple example:

```
DECLARE @D decimal(10, 6) = 0.058823,
        @S decimal(10, 6) = 5.8823e-02

SELECT  @D As Regular, 
        @S As Scientific, 
        IIF(@D = @S, 1, 0) As AreEqual
```

The result of this select statement is:

```
Regular     Scientific  AreEqual
0.058823    0.058823    1
```

**However**, casting from `varchar` to decimal works perfectly with regular decimals, but raises an error with scientific notation:

```
DECLARE @SD varchar(10) = '0.058823',
        @SS varchar(10) = '5.8823e-02'                 

SELECT CAST(@SD AS decimal(10, 6)) As RegularString,
       CAST(@SS AS decimal(10, 6)) As ScientificString
```

raise this error:

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Casting to float, on the other hand, works perfectly - so to get a decimal you can cast to float and then to decimal:

```
SELECT  CAST(@SD AS decimal(10, 6)) As RegularString,
        CAST(CAST(@SS AS float) AS decimal(10, 6)) As ScientificString
```

Results:

```
RegularString   ScientificString
0,058823        0,058823
```

Comment: Casting it twice by first turning it to float and then to decimal does exactly what I want it to. Thank you so much for the explanation and tip.

Answer (score 0):

Since your main concern seems to be the code bloat (600 lines vs. 100), you can create a function

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetDecimal(@input VARCHAR(32))
RETURNS DECIMAL(30,20)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN CAST(CAST(@input AS FLOAT) AS DECIMAL (30, 20)) 
END
```

and call it in your SELECT statement for each field to be converted, like this:

```
SELECT 
  dbo.GetDecimal(sfield1) as tfield1,
  dbo.GetDecimal(sfield2) as tfield2,
  ...
FROM ...
```

*Note: the first comment on your question correctly pointed out that you should not be using the log() function.  Instead, this user function does an intermediate cast to float before the final cast to decimal. This is necessary because string values expressed in scientific notation cannot be cast directly to decimal.*