# Not able to convert directly to decimal value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, type-conversion

I have the following string and want to convert it to `DECIMAL(38,0)`:

```
a321
```

The following code is OK:

```
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(binary(2), 'a321', 2) AS BIGINT);  -- 41761
```

but this one fails:

```
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(binary(2), 'a321', 2) AS DECIMAL(38,0));
```

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 7 Error converting data type
>   varbinary to numeric.

It is not a big deal to do two casts like this:

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(CONVERT(binary(2), 'a321', 2) AS BIGINT) AS DECIMAL(38,0));
```

but I want to know why is not working. Can anyone explain?

Comment: Good question +1, especially since the SQL Server official [data type conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-conversion-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017) matrix seems to be saying that your second query should work.

Comment: Here's one even stranger: You can cast `'5.23e-4'` to `float`, but not to `decimal` - a double conversion works like a charm - but you can use scientific notation for decimals - `declare @d decimal(10,5) = 5.23e-4` works perfectly. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54921174/3094533

Comment: The issue might be to do with the size of the input.  Decimal numbers need more space.  See - https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/87199/what-is-the-cause-of-this-problem-with-convert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be because the number you are trying to convert is an **integer**, not a *decimal*.

```
SELECT CAST(41761 AS VARBINARY), CAST(41761.0 as VARBINARY)
```

The above give different results as I suspect that the later carries information about the decimal component.  Likewise, when converting the decimal value to binary, it works as expected.

```
SELECT CAST(41761.0 as VARBINARY) -- gives 0x060100014A5F0600 on Azure SQL
SELECT CAST(0x060100014A5F0600 as DECIMAL) -- gives 41761 on Azure SQL
```

I have tagged the server in as [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) states the results may very between versions.

> Do not construct binary values, and then convert them to a data type of the numeric data type category. SQL Server does not guarantee that the result of a decimal or numeric data type conversion, to binary, will be the same between versions of SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks for the quote for the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Convert to a `bigint` first and then convert to a decimal:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(38, 0), CONVERT(BIGINT, CONVERT(binary(2), 'a321', 2)))
```

The binary representation of decimals is quite different from integers, and not all binary representations can be converted to a decimal.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question, "but I want to know why is not working"

Comment: @TabAlleman . . . I think the last line is that answer, but I elaborated.

Comment: Why would a binary that can be converted to an integer not be convertible to a decimal?   Is this documented in a more detailed article somewhere?